# How can I set an entry in the Windows DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

We have 2 domain controllers that also do the DNS. The DHCP assigns these 2 servers to filter all the DNS traffic.

For exchange 2010 we need to create an internal DNS entry for the mail.domain.com entry so that it routes it through the network vs going out and getting blocked by the ASA 5505.

Do you guys know where I would go about to setting this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server: Start Menu > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > DNS

Then add an A record for `mail` and point it to the right IP. You will have to do this twice if the DNS-server don't replicate one another.

[image: Change 'Accounts' with 'mail']

Change 'Accounts' with 'mail'

Comment: this took care of it!!! Thank you (^_^) I had to put it as mail.domain.com though because it broke our external website (on the domain) but once I knew where to go it was easy to get the rest done. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

http://www.howtonetworking.com/domain/w2008dns2.htm

Quick answer.

1. Open DNS manager.
2. Select the appropriate Forward Lookup Zone
3. Right click select New
   Host (A or AAAA)
4. Enter "mail" for name  Enter the internal IP
   address Check the "create associate pointer (PTR) if you have a
   reverse lookup zone setup
5. profit

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate internal DNS namespace from your external DNS namespace, then you need to create a new zone in order to resolve the domain name you want. So pick either DNS server. Add a new DNS zone for mail2.exampledomain.com and set it to replicate to all DCs in the domain. Create an A record in the zone leaving the name blank and using the internal IP address of the Exchange server.